# Shell script ls pointing to n-th file

Tags: linux, shell

I want to develop a script for my linux system and I need a function which returns the n-th file in a path. For instance, if I have the subsequent files in a path:

```
my_path
  |_file1
  |_file2
  |_file3
  |_file4
  |_file5
```

I want a function that returns the n-th file name. Is it possible? I don't know how...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Homework? ;)

This should do it:

```
find my_path -type f | head -3 | tail -1
```

replace '3' with your 'n'.  The above will be recursive.  If you just want files in 'my_path', replace find with simple ls.

Obviously, the definition of 'n' depends on the sorting order.  You might want to consider throwing a 'sort' before head.

Comment: hahaha yeah, I didn't thought in this solution... Thank you!!! :D

No it isn't homework. I'm working on a music player for my openWrt Router using mpd package, and I want to select a folder each time to do a playlist.

Comment: Replacing `head | tail -n1` with a single script is worth knowing; `sed -n '3!d;p;q'`